# Image Resize without cropping and maintaing aspect ratio

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imageview, imagick

I want to resize images uploaded on server but without cropping so as to show them full version of image .

Basic idea is i just want to show users images in full size(which is resized one) and let them download original files.

Say if anyone uploads an image with large resolution and size is 10MB then it will take time if i load whole image in gallery or something. Thats why i just need to resize iamge to small scale showing everything and reduced size.

I am using imagick but not getting how to do maths for this, and only know to crop.

I know i can just decrease width of image and let it automatically adjust height, But still stuck how much i need to reduce it.

I would be thankful if anyone can explain it.

DropBox uses this it let you upload a image of any size but in gallery it shows image with less resolution and reduced size. But note: that any part of image is not cropped.

EDIT:
For example if user upload image of Dimension 2496 × 1404 and size 3MB. 
I need image that should have less dimension say like 1280 x 960 and size less than 1MB in order to use for gallery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation of imagemagick:
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#thumbnail

---

Or, if you are using it in code:

```
$width = 100; 
$height = 300; 

$ratio = $width / $height; // get ratio by dividing width by height

$newWidth = 200; // a random new width
$newHeight = $newWidth / $ratio; // devide by ratio to get new width (600 in this case)
// OR, if you have a new height:
$newHeight = 200;
$newWidth = $newHeight * $ratio; // multiply instead of devide
```

Dont forget to use `round()` in the end if you want to make actual pixels of it (which I asume you will)

---

Coming back here I thought of another solution (which actually is easier):

```
$width = 100; 
$height = 300; 

$newWidth = 200;
$newHeight = ($newWidth/$width) * $height;
```

The `$newWidth/$width` part calculates how much the width has changed (in my example it will result in `2`), so the height getschanged in the same ratio. Same works of you turn it arround for if you want `$newWidth` based on height.